# Real analysis question $ a = b$ if and only if for every $\epsilon \gt 0, \left\lvert a-b \right\rvert \lt \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, absolute-value

I've encountered the proof that BWOC, $|a-b| \lt \epsilon$, we assume that $a \ne b.$

Without loss of generality, $a\gt b, a-b\gt 0$, let $\epsilon = a-b.$ Then $|a-b| \lt a-b$, which is a contradiction. Thus $a=b$.

I do not get which part of it is a contradiction.

PS. I'm completely new to stack exchange, so if my wording is weird, please let me know how I should phrase the questions next time so that you understand them better! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $a>b$ then $a-b>0$ so $|a-b|=a-b.\quad$   $a-b<a-b$ is a contradiction

Comment: "I do not get which part of it is a contradiction"  The final part... $|a-b|$ cannot be less than $a-b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a-b > 0$, $|a-b|=a-b < a-b$.

The same number can't be less than itself. This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If $|d| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$, then we must have $d=0$, because if not,
then setting $\epsilon = {1 \over 2} |d|$ will yield $1 < {1 \over 2}$ which is a contradiction.

Set $d=a-b$ in the above.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about it, but thank you for the new insight

Comment: If it is any consolation, it took me a while to understand when I encountered it first, many decades ago.